# How to put 2 elements into 2 separate lists?

Tags: python

I currently am iterating through a list and splitting up 2 elements at a ':'. It then results in 2 elements: user, and password. I would like to then make 2 lists, one for user and one for password. Right now these are both stored in a list called lines. I would like to store them in 2 lists, user and password. The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to pull each of them individually later on to send an email to the user with their password.

I tried appending these 2 elements into 2 separate lists but kept getting errors. Do I need to use a dictionary?

```
lines = []
#open txt file
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #only return lines that contain 'Success'
        if 'Success' in line:
            lines.append(line[:line.find('Success')-1])
for element in lines:
    user, password = element.strip().split(":")
    print(user,password)
```

Current output lists each user with their password. But I want to be able to later pull each user and send them an email and tell them what their password is. I though the next step would be to put their username and passwords into 2 separate lists. Ideas?

Comment: (1) "_I want to be able to pull each of them individually_" ... _pull_ ? Not sure what you mean there... (2) "_I tried appending these 2 elements into 2 separate lists but kept getting errors_" What were your errors?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of "output.txt"?

Comment: 1) what errors? 2) Can you show the code where you tried to store them in 2 separate lists? It's useful to give an example of what you expect to happen (you have) and what is happening (you have not) 3) I'm assuming you're using this for some experiment or as a programming exercise but this is just a warning to not use this in production

Comment: To me it sounds like you don't want two lists but one list of tuples. This way you can make sure you do not accidentally shift one list and get wrong passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. With two separate lists your code looks like:

```
#open txt file
listuser = []
listpwd = []
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #only return lines that contain 'Success'
        if 'Success' in line:
            ll = line[:line.find('Success')-1]
            user, password = ll.strip().split(":")
            print(user, password)
            listuser.append(user)
            listpwd.append(password)
```

Similar but with a dictionary. Be sure that there are not users with the same username, dictionary keys must be unique.

```
#open txt file
userpwd = {}
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #only return lines that contain 'Success'
        if 'Success' in line:
            ll = line[:line.find('Success')-1]
            print(user, password)
            user, password = ll.strip().split(":")
            userpwd[user] = password
```

Comment: `for line in f.readlines():` can be just `for line in f:` also.

Comment: I used the list method you provided, but nothing is printing

def get_users():
        listuser=[]
        listpwd=[]
        with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                        if 'Success' in line:
                                ll=line[:line.find('Success')-1]
                                user, password = ll.strip().split(":")
                                listuser.append(user)
                                listpwd.append(password)
                        return listuser,listpwd
get_users()

Comment: @user10998118 I removed the print function from my code. If you want to print it from the `get_user()` function, just add `print' again. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a dictionary would be a good idea unless you have two users with the same user name. In that case, this won't work.
Here is an example code -

```
userPass = {}
for element in lines:
   user,password = element.strip().split(':')
   userPass[user] = password
```

For the two users with the same usernames, it would replace the current user with previously stored user.